# Angular [mat-dialog-close]="false" does not work

Tags: html, angular, mat-dialog

Is there a certain reason, why `[mat-dialog-close]="createFurtherCheckbox.checked ? 'false' : 'true'"` does not work, if the value for `[mat-dialog-close]` is `false`? Within a dialog I create an object by clicking a submit button and if a certain checkbox is checked, which is questioning if I want to create another object, the dialogbox shall not close, so I can create another object (in this case a course). I want the dialog to reset and stay open, if the checkbox ist checked.

Even if I try `[mat-dialog-close]="false"` the dialog closes.

However `[type]="createAnotherCheckbox.checked ? 'reset' : 'button'"` does the 'reset'-type change correctly. (Used to reset the formControls within a form)

**create-course-dialog.component.html**

```
<mat-dialog-actions>
    <mat-checkbox #createFurtherCheckbox>Create another course?</mat-checkbox>
    <button mat-raised-button [mat-dialog-close]="createFurtherCheckbox.checked ? 'false' : 'true'" [type]="createFurtherCheckbox.checked ? 'reset' : 'button'"
            (click)="Submit()" [disabled]="courseForm.invalid">Create course</button>
    <button mat-raised-button mat-dialog-close>Cancel</button>
</mat-dialog-actions>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you misunderstand the input of the [mat-dialog-close directive](https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/api#MatDialogClose).

```
@Input('mat-dialog-close')
dialogResult: any
```

You are setting the return value for the result you get when you subscribe to afterClosed
like here

```
dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
      console.log('The dialog was closed');
      this.animal = result;
    });
```

fast workaround with ngif and two buttons

```
<ng-container *ngIf="createAnotherCheckbox.checked">
   <button mat-raised-button type="reset" (click)="Submit()" [disabled]="courseForm.invalid">
    Create course</button>
</ng-container>
<ng-container *ngIf="!createAnotherCheckbox.checked">
   <button mat-raised-button type="button" (click)="Submit()" [disabled]="courseForm.invalid" 
    mat-dialog-close>Create course</button>
</ng-container>
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay thanks, you are right.
I fixed my issue by using two ng-container:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="createAnotherCheckbox.checked">
   <button mat-raised-button type="reset" (click)="Submit()" [disabled]="courseForm.invalid">
    Create course</button>
</ng-container>
<ng-container *ngIf="!createAnotherCheckbox.checked">
   <button mat-raised-button type="button" (click)="Submit()" [disabled]="courseForm.invalid" 
    mat-dialog-close>Create course</button>
</ng-container>
```